# QML: Issue while renderring qml screen

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I am facing problem while rendering QML screen on one of the development boards

On some of the screens I have throbber gif image where I can see the background color of the screen as shown in this image. 
[image: Issue of refresh in QML]

on some screen I have list view which I am updating through JavaScript, which is not taking effect as I am not able to see the updated image/text in the list view elements.

Is this some kind of issue related to refreshing screen .

The same code runs fine on Ix86 when compiled with QML on IX86.

Comment: I'm facing very similar behaviour - were you able to determine the cause of this?

Comment: This looks like a problem with detecting or handling transparency in the OpenGL drivers of your platform - as your results on X86 tend to confirm. Can you post a minimal test case of your QML code and which board, OpenGL vendor and driver you're using?

Answer (score 0):

If the same code is fine when compiled for another platform, I expect the first platform has a buggy library.